# Only show opaque objects behind transparent objects

Tags: graphics, three.js, transparency

I am using three.js and WebGl. I would like to make certain objects in my scene transparent, and only show opaque objects behind the transparent objects, not other transparent objects.

Currently, when I make objects transparent, I can see other transparent objects behind them, which I don't want.

This is what happens now:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Is there a term for this type of transparency rendering? It seems like I could accomplish this with multiple rendering passes.

I am working with three.js and WebGl but I haven't found a solution yet in any language, so I am open to any generic tips.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is to only render the front most layer of transparent objects, you can try this:

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); 

// dont write to color buffer, only to depth
gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL); 
gl.colorMask(false, false, false, false); 

drawTransparentObjects();

// only draw to front most layer
gl.depthFunc(gl.EQUAL); 
gl.colorMask(true, true, true, true); 

drawTransparentObjects();

// switch back to normal depth testing 
gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I want, but it is closer than I what I have now. Even if an object is in the front most layer, I don't want to render the overlapping sections of its faces that are behind its front faces.

Comment: Im afraid I dont understand the effect you are looking for. Perhaps add more pictures to illustrate?

Comment: What I want is essentially for the transparent objects to be rendered opaque, then take that 2d rendered image of the transparent objects and make it transparent. Then overlay it over the top of the opaque objects. Let me know if that doesn't make sense and I can make a graphic.

Comment: Is this answer really relevant to three.js? Three.js sets depth functions based on materials so these examples won't work with three.js will they?

Comment: OP did say he is "open to any generic tips" and this question had a webgl tab which you removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing but I think this would work

```
// at init time
renderer.autoClear = false;

// at render time
renderer.clear(true, true, true);
renderer.render( sceneOfObjectsYouWantInBack, camera)
renderer.clear(false, true, true);
renderer.render( sceneOfObjectsYouWantInMiddle, camera)
renderer.clear(false, true, true);
renderer.render( sceneOfObjectsYouWantInFront, camera)
renderer.clear(false, true, true);
```